$L_p$ inequality for measurable sets
Let $(U,\mu)$ a finite and positive measure space, and $1\leq p<\infty$. Suppose that for every $\varepsilon$ and measurable subset $A\subset U$, there exists a measurable subset $B\subset U$ such that $$|\mu(A\cap B)-\mu(B)|<\varepsilon,$$ and $$|\mu(A\cap B)-\mu(A)|<\varepsilon.$$ I want to prove that $$||\chi_A-\chi_B||_p<(2\varepsilon)^{1/p}.$$ My work: Let $C:=A\cap B$, then by triangular inequality, $$||\chi_A-\chi_B||_p\leq ||\chi_A-\chi_C||_p+||\chi_C-\chi_B||_p,$$ and $$||\chi_A-\chi_C||_p=\left(\int_U|\chi_A(t)-\chi_C(t)|^p dt\right)^{1/p},$$ but i am not sure that last term is something like $|\mu(A)-\mu(C)|^p$ or something related.  I think the reasoning must be something like that but i'm not seeing it. Any advice? Thanks in advance

By triangle inequality
$$
\int |\chi_A - \chi_B| = \mu(A\setminus B) + \mu(B \setminus A)
= \mu(A) - \mu(A \cap B) + \mu(B)-\mu(A\cap B) \le 2\epsilon
$$
Then by Hoelder inequality
$$
\|\chi_A - \chi_B\|_{L^p}^p \le \|\chi_A - \chi_B\|_{L^1}^1 \|\chi_A - \chi_B\|_{L^\infty}^{p-1} \le 2\epsilon.
$$

Nice! But i don't understand well how you used the triangle inequality. Could you please elaborate more?

that is only the last step. From left to right: check integrand pointwise, then express measure of set difference as difference of measures, triangle inequality.

$$|\chi_A-\chi_B|_p^p=|\chi_A-\chi_B|_1=\mu(A\triangle B)<2\varepsilon $$ where $$A\triangle B=(A\setminus B)\cup (B\setminus A)=(A\setminus ( A\cap B))\cup (B\setminus (A\cap B))$$
